# Rails logging 127.0.0.1 every 5 minutes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, localhost, production-environment

I have noticed in my production Rails log that exactly every 5 minutes, I have a GET request to my root url from 127.0.0.1 which apparently is my localhost.

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-07-01 14:05:03 -0500
  Processing by ApplicationController#landing as */*
Rendered shared/_header.html.erb (0.9ms)
Rendered shared/_footer.html.erb (0.5ms)
Rendered application/landing.html.erb (5.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 8ms (Views: 7.9ms)
```

I have never seen this in any other Rails apps. I am using New Relic, MongoDB, Nginx, and Unicorn. Can anyone tell my why this is happening or what it means?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a monitoring application, especially since it's only checking the root path for a successful connection (i.e. HTTP 200).  Have you installed any tools such as monit?  What hosting provider are you using?  They may monitor without you knowing.

Comment: It's coming from localhost, so maybe not.  I use rackspace and notice similar internal requests.